# Can a Pi back itself up?

Tags: networking, sd-card, backup

I am looking for a way to have the Pi create an image of it's SD card and send it off to a networked file share in a repeatable manner, and then resume operations. I imagine that it would need the entire OS in ram during this time, or at have everything mounted in read-only mode, however I am unsure about this - does anyone have ideas or something similar setup?

non-solutions:
anything that would require manual intervention, especially physically moving the SD card into something else - this needs to be able to be completely automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that doing a bare metal backup on a running system needs some crafting. I'm thinking of two possible solutions:

1. Crate a tarbal archive of the filesystem contents and send it away. This isn't exactly a bare metal backup but may be close enough.
2. Use an OS which runs entirely from RAM. My project [Nard SDK](http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/) does exactly this. After bootup the SD-card is left alone and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I am already doing the equivalent of #1, but have had issues with the backups not being correct, so I am moving away from that - #2 may work, however I would like a solution that doesn't cripple the Pi 99% of the time and simply toggles between states if possible.

Comment: OK, how about dual booting? The system could reboot into a small RAM-based OS when it's time for backup and then reboot again when the backup has finished, this time into the "ordinary" OS and resume normal operation.

Comment: That could work, I will need to look into it (and how to control which of the two systems it boots into automatically)

Comment: One method could be to have two /boot/config.txt and switch between them, but there are a number or other options too.

Answer (score 4):

From my linux machine I run

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.38 sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/mmcblk0 | gzip -c > raspberry_dd_4M.img.gz
```

and I just make a point of not doing too much with the pi while its running.
192.168.1.38 is the ip of the Pi

Comment: and to recover to an SD card on the linux machine gunzip -dc /home/user/raspberry_dd_4M.img.gz | dd bs=4M of=/dev/sdc

Comment: Is there any way to be more sure that you "aren't doing too much" while this is running? i.e. suspend all other threads or something?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the how you create a NOOBS installer, in which you make tarballs from the running operating system:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs

You can then, if you wish, compress those tarballs with `xz`into a NOOBS folder structure which can be copied to an SD and either self-install or menu-install if booted from. I have used this process for my own [Raspple II](http://ivanx.com/rasppleii/) distribution of Raspbian if you want to look at that as a template.

The actual commands I use to make the tarballs (modified from the NOOBS docs) is:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/usbdisk; sudo mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/usbdisk;
sudo rm /tmp/usbdisk/BOOT.TAR &> /dev/null;
pwd="$PWD"; cd /boot; sudo tar -cvpf /tmp/usbdisk/BOOT.TAR .; cd "$pwd";
sudo umount /dev/sda1; rmdir /tmp/usbdisk

mkdir -p /tmp/usbdisk; sudo mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/usbdisk;
sudo rm /tmp/usbdisk/ROOT.TAR &> /dev/null;
sudo tar -cvpf /tmp/usbdisk/ROOT.TAR /* --exclude=proc/* --exclude=sys/* \
--exclude=dev/pts/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/var/swap --exclude=/boot/*;
sudo umount /dev/sda1; rmdir /tmp/usbdisk
```

Once you have the tarball, you need to compress it with `xz` (as explained in the NOOBS link above) if you want to make it usable with NOOBS, which will probably take all day and night on the Pi; if I use max compression (with the `-9 -e` options), it takes about an hour to compress on my 1.7 GHz mobile i7 with SSD.

Also, if you do want to use the self-install option (`silentinstall`), the Raspple II build of NOOBS incorporates a bug fix in which, when Ethernet is attached, the progress bar remains visible and the Pi reboots after installation instead of crashing. This bug fix has not made it into a distribution version of NOOBS yet, though it's in the development branch.